# Setting up pinia persistent store on an individual web page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a simple vue js app and its only for one page only but i also want to access pinia stores when a i navigate to another page of the larger app.

I have setup vue 3, pinia and pinia persistent storage like this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pinia/2.0.14/pinia.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia-plugin-persistedstate-2"></script>
```

This works

```
const { createApp } = Vue

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        firstname: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
```

Since pinia and pinia persistent state are available on the cdn, how can i port this to work entirely on the browser and can i access the stored data if i navigate to another browser page?

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { createPersistedStatePlugin } from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate-2'

export const useStore = defineStore('main', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      someState: 'hello pinia',
    }
  },
  persist: true,
})
```

Comment: if you're using the default persisted storage for that library (i.e. localStorage - and since there's no mention of any alternative storage in your code, then I assume that IS the storage you are using) then the only way to different "Apps" could possibly share the data is if they are on the same domain

Comment: Yeah, i think the default data storage mechanism is localstorage. The setup on the browser itself is a problem even before trying to access my store from another page.

Comment: localStorage can't be used cross domain at all, ever, no amount of setup will change that

Comment: I think i am going to have to watch data variables i am interested in. If they change i update local storage and access them on the other page. and inside the page.

Comment: yes - that works if both "sites" are same domain ... I think you can add an event listener on localStorage so that you get "real time" changes if you have the sites open in two tabs for example